# How to make a precise polar stretch in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

I want to take a pattern and stretch it within concentric circles with the centers being the same. I'm trying to make guidelines for a laser cut piece of cardboard to test out an idea.

The pattern is already an arc, but the sector angle is wrong. No original rectangular artwork exists, so I cannot solve the case by making a new, but wider bend.

After a lot of thinking I've realized that what I want to do is to take the 60 degree arc wedge below and apply a polar stretch of any degree so that the end result would still precisely align with the concentric circles.

For example from a 60 degree arc to a 90 degree arc. If I'm unable to figure this out I'd have to manually rotate my design by one degree or something small to trace it out.

[image]

Comment: If the original piece of the design happens to be a horizontal rectangular area you can apply Object > Envelope distort > Make with Warp > Arc. Or you can apply Art Brush to a circular arc. Or you can map the piece as art onto a cone which is made with Effect > 3D > Revolve . If your artwork happens to be already an arc these are useless, of course. Is it already an arc?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that, thanks for asking, that is an important factor, yes the artwork is already an arc

Comment: I inserted this to the question. Check it and revert the edit to the original if it's not right.